# Need help in getting an element from mongodb document and updating its value using go mongo drivers

Tags: mongodb, go

Hey there I am using the [go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) package to work with golang. This is my code:

```golang
package src

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

var (
    client      *mongo.Client
    stickerscol *mongo.Collection
)

func init() {
    log.Println("Setting up database...")
    var err error
    client, err = mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI(Envars.DbUrl))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connected to database")
    stickerscol = client.Database("stickersbot").Collection("stickers")
    chatcol = client.Database("stickersbot").Collection("chat")
}

func ChangeDefaultPack(userid int64, stickername string, format string) error {
    fmt.Println(userid, stickername, format)
    filter := bson.M{
        "_id":                      userid,
        "stickers.stickername":     stickername,
        "stickers.stickerpacktype": format,
    }
    updateOther := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "stickers.$[elem].isdefault": false,
        },
    }
    update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "stickers.$.isdefault": true,
        },
    }
    arrayFilters := options.ArrayFilters{
        Filters: []interface{}{bson.M{"elem.stickerpacktype": format}},
    }
    updateOptions := options.Update().SetArrayFilters(arrayFilters)
    _, err := stickerscol.UpdateMany(context.TODO(), filter, updateOther, updateOptions)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    ok, err := stickerscol.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update, options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if ok.ModifiedCount == 0 {
        fmt.Println("no document matched")
        return fmt.Errorf("no document matched")
    }
    return err
}
```

And this is the db structure:

```
...
{
  "_id": 1633375527,
  "stickers": [
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "gVtOy_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": true
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "animated",
      "stickername": "zIjsa_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": true
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "video",
      "stickername": "bJBle_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": true
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "iujiw_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "video",
      "stickername": "CHnqb_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "XKJUP_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "animated",
      "stickername": "pCFlC_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "animated",
      "stickername": "jGGgt_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "animated",
      "stickername": "cTxyA_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "animated",
      "stickername": "ZfYXO_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "xJUkA_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "HIvsY_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "WIHFQ_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "OqjtE_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "QNysO_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "OrTsT_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "FzROg_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "QUBcT_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "NsZfM_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "AkxVM_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "Ddvus_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "LXfHV_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "sTaMv_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    },
    {
      "stickerpacktype": "static",
      "stickername": "vppgK_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
      "isdefault": false
    }
  ],
  "stickerpackcount": 2
}
...
```

What I need my code is to find list of sticker packs which matches the given id and sticker type and set their default value to `false` and set the default value of the pack which is passed to the func as `true`.

Basically just making one as default and others as not default. Could someone explain me why this function is returning no document found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are multiple field matches, you should use the `$elemMatch` operator. Otherwise, the `$` operator does not work. See [Update Embedded Documents Using Multiple Field Matches](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-embedded-documents-using-multiple-field-matches).

And you don't need `UpdateMany` to update multiple array elements in a single document. Use `UpdateOne` instead.

Here is the demo based on your code and data:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

var (
    client      *mongo.Client
    stickerscol *mongo.Collection
)

func init() {
    log.Println("Setting up database...")
    var err error
    client, err = mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connected to database")
    stickerscol = client.Database("stickersbot").Collection("stickers")
}

func ChangeDefaultPack(userid int64, stickername string, format string) error {
    fmt.Println(userid, stickername, format)
    filter := bson.M{
        "_id": userid,
        "stickers": bson.M{
            "$elemMatch": bson.M{
                "stickername":     stickername,
                "stickerpacktype": format,
            },
        },
    }
    updateOther := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "stickers.$[elem].isdefault": false,
        },
    }
    arrayFilters := options.ArrayFilters{
        Filters: []interface{}{bson.M{"elem.stickerpacktype": format}},
    }
    updateOptions := options.Update().SetArrayFilters(arrayFilters)
    result, err := stickerscol.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, updateOther, updateOptions)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Printf("update other: %+v\n", result)

    update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "stickers.$.isdefault": true,
        },
    }
    ok, err := stickerscol.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update, options.Update().SetUpsert(true))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Printf("update default: %+v\n", ok)
    if ok.ModifiedCount == 0 {
        fmt.Println("no document matched")
        return fmt.Errorf("no document matched")
    }
    return err
}

func main() {
    if err := ChangeDefaultPack(1633375527, "Ddvus_1633375527_by_ChadManBot", "static"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Run the demo and you will observe the following change to the document:

```
--- before.json 2023-06-27 00:34:32.721978745 +0800
+++ after.json  2023-06-27 00:34:59.489836137 +0800
@@ -4,7 +4,7 @@
     {
       "stickerpacktype": "static",
       "stickername": "gVtOy_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
-      "isdefault": true
+      "isdefault": false
     },
     {
       "stickerpacktype": "animated",
@@ -104,7 +104,7 @@
     {
       "stickerpacktype": "static",
       "stickername": "Ddvus_1633375527_by_ChadManBot",
-      "isdefault": false
+      "isdefault": true
     },
     {
       "stickerpacktype": "static",
```

Comment: coool. Thanks It Worked Out